# What effect do urban wind conditions have on operating tiltwing aircraft and gyrocopters?

Tags: helicopter, autogyro, tiltrotor, helipad

From [this research](https://www.coolgeography.co.uk/A-level/AQA/Year%2013/Weather%20and%20climate/Microclimates/Urban_climates.htm) it seems there are quite a lot of strong wind in suburb residential area and around high-rise buildings. High-rise buildings would also create wind tunnel effect and eddy winds.

When trying to land or takeoff in heliports, or rooftop helicopter pads, would the wind cause the tilt wing or tilt rotor aircraft to flip or move around? Would the wind big enough that when the wing rotated 90 degree, the wind could push the aircraft away from the desire landing spot?

If it is a gyrocopter, would the rush of city wind, or even the eddy wind, drive the top rotor harder so the landing or takeoff becomes an issue?

Comment: A tiltrotor in landing configuration is for all practical purposes a normal helicopter with two relatively inefficient rotors.

Comment: A gyrocopter might be able to land on a rooftop helipad if you time the flare just right (due to lack of collective it is no longer controllable when it stops moving forward, making it difficult), but it needs runway to take off, so no take-off from helipad.

Comment: It isn't totally clear to me what you are asking.  Do you think the effects of wind on tilt rotor or gyrocopters is different than it is on traditional helicopters?